# where to find source code link

Tags: android, android-source

i want to dowmload android source  as repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git -b android-2.2_r1,i know the method of downloads ,but i donot know  where to find "android-2.2_r1" ,if i want to find 2.1, how to modify the  parameter after -b,could you give a link that tell me which versions may be download. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [repo guide](http://source.android.com/source/git-repo.html)

> ### Using topic branches
>
> To assign the
>   branch to a particular project:
>
> ```
> $ repo start branch name project
> ```
>
> To switch back and forth among
>   branches that you have created in your
>   local work environment:
>
> ```
> $ git checkout branchname
> ```
>
> To see a list of existing branches:
>
> ```
> $ git branch
> ```
>
> or...
>
> ```
> $ repo branches
> ```

Comment: I should have read your answer before writing mine actually. :p

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://android.git.kernel.org)   is the complete guide and
 [Here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gittutorial.html)  is the complete tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Clone the entire project using the `repo` tool and let git show you all available branches using `git branch`. That way you can fund out how the 2.1 branch is called and the just issue a `git checkout [thebranch]` to switch to the desired branch.